# How can I change the title of a Windows help window?

Tags: windows, titlebar

To change the title of a help window, [Microsoft says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms524416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to "Open a project (`.hhp`) file, and then click Add/Modify Window Definitions" but gives no clue what tool to open it with. I've tried VS and I've tried double clicking in Explorer (I get an error).  Neither seems to help.  I imagine it's a directive in the help project but I can't find it.

Comment: Added clarifying info from title into actual question.

Comment: Open it in HTML Help Workshop, which is part of the HTML Help package from MS (if it's still available). [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms670169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) lists the contents of HTML Help.

Comment: Thanks.  I used the HTML Help Workshop, edited the file as directed... and it had no effect. :-(

Answer (score 0):

As Ken White suggested, HTML Help Workshop is the tool to edit the `.hhp` file.  The reason that didn't work for me seems to be that the person who created this (English) help project set the language in the `[OPTIONS]` section to French.  When I set it to English, the `MAIN=` setting added by the Workshop takes effect in the generated help.